Passing argument from incompatible pointer type. Expected char** but argument is of type char(*)[][]
I am trying to compile the following piece of C code:
void bar(char** foo) {
  foo[0][0] = '\0';
}

int main() {
  char foo[1][1];
  bar(&foo);
}

and I get the following warning:
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘bar’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    7 |   bar(&foo);
      |       ^~~~
      |       |
      |       char (*)[1][1]
main.c:1:17: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[1][1]’
    1 | void bar(char** foo) {
      |          ~~~~~~~^~~


Please tell me how I can handle that? I can only change the signature of the bar function.

You can change bar to accept char foo[][1], and then call with bar(foo). See demo.

@wohlstad what If I don't know in advance the 1 part? I would like to work with an arbitrarily sized matrix.

&foo in main produces the pointer to the 2d array, not pointer to pointer as required by bar function.
You need to modify your function if you want to pass parameters this way.
void bar(size_t cols, size_t rows, char (*foo)[rows][cols]) {
  (*foo)[0][0] = '\0';
  // (*foo) is giving a 2d char array
  // then you can index it normally
}

int main() {
  char foo[1][1];
  bar(1,1,&foo);
}

or better
void bar(size_t cols, size_t row, size_t col, char (*foo)[cols]) {
  foo[row][col] = '\0';
}

int main() {
  char foo[5][10];
  bar(10, 3, 2, foo);
  //it will set foo[3][2] to '\0'
}

or if your compiler does not support VLAs
void bar(char (*foo)[5][10]) {
  (*foo)[0][0] = '\0';
}

int main() {
  char foo[5][10];
  bar(&foo);
}

or if you do not know the size of the array in advance and toyr compiler does not support VLAs
void bar(size_t cols, size_t rows, size_t row, size_t col, void *foo) {
  char *cfoo = foo;

  cfoo[row * cols + col] = '\0';
}

int main() {
  char foo[5][10];
  bar(5,10,2,3,foo);
  // it will set foo[2][3] to '\0'
}


In void bar(size_t cols, size_t row, size_t col, char (*foo)[cols]), col and cols can be confusing.  Maybe something like void bar(size_t updateElementRow, size_t updateElementCol, size_t arrayCols, char (*foo)[arrayCols])?  I'd think the argument denoting the number of columns in the array should be adjacent to the array argument.
